# What does "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" mean?

Tags: support, comment, editing

I wrote a comment following an answer. A few minutes later, I see a horrible typo.  So I edit my comment, click "Save Edits" but get a little red pop-up box saying "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes".   Why can't I save my correction?  What does five minutes have to do with anything?

Comment: This FAQ posts contains many details about comments: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) You might be interested in the section *Who can edit comments?* Specifically, this describes your situations: "Users may edit their own comments any number of times for five minutes after they are first posted."

Comment: A related older post on this meta: [Why can I not edit a comment after 5 minutes but can just replace it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20721) Other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20721) are about the same topic.

Answer (score 16):

Comments are second-class citizens on the StackExchange network.

As such, they are only allowed to be edited in a short five minutes window. If your edit was submitted outside this window, you will see this red error message.

What can you do? If this is a fresh new comment, delete the old one and post a correct version. If the conversation already rolled onward and your comment received replies, it's best to leave a clarification.